# Centering UI elements in middle of screen programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm trying to do something fairly simple, but just can't manage to make it happen. I have an UIImage followed by two UILabels, each on on top of the other, that I want to center in the middle of a UIView.

```
(empty space)
   UIImage
   UILabel
   UILabel
(empty space)
```

This is what I have so far:

```
UIView* baseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width,[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.height)];
UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 175, 175)];
UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50)];
UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50)];

[imageView setCenter:CGPointMake(baseView.frame.size.width / 2, baseView.frame.size.height / 2)];
[label1 setCenter:CGPointMake(baseView.frame.size.width / 2, baseView.frame.size.height / 2)];
[label2 setCenter:CGPointMake(baseView.frame.size.width / 2, baseView.frame.size.height / 2)];

[baseView addSubview:imageView];
[baseView addSubview:label1];
[baseView addSubview:label2];
[self addSubview:baseView];
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. All the elements are over each other. Any ideas?

Comment: All the three view have the same center property, the one above will cover the one below. What do you want?

Comment: one on top of the other

Comment: It's because you gave them the same coordinates in the view.

Comment: how do I know which coordinates to give them?

Comment: Add the heights of all 3 elements.  Subtract that from baseView height to get empty space height.  Divide that by 2, to get top empty space.  Use that value as UIImage y value.  UILabel's y value is UIImage's y+height.  UILabel2's y is UILabel1's y+height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it a try.

I add an container view to hold the imageView and the two labels, then center the `container` view in `baseView`. Set backgroundColor of `container` to clear color so we can't see it.

```
UIView* baseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width,[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.height)];
UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 175, 175)];
UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50)];
UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50)];

UIView * container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 175+50+50)] ;
container.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor] ;

[imageView setCenter:CGPointMake(container.bounds.size.width/2, imageView.bounds.size.height/2)];
[label1 setCenter:CGPointMake(imageView.center.x, imageView.bounds.size.height + label1.bounds.size.height / 2)];
[label2 setCenter:CGPointMake(imageView.center.x, label1.frame.origin.y + label1.bounds.size.height + label2.bounds.size.height / 2)];

container.center = CGPointMake(baseView.bounds.size.width/2, baseView.bounds.size.height/2) ;

[container addSubview:imageView];
[container addSubview:label1];
[container addSubview:label2];

[baseView addSubview:container] ;

[self addSubview:baseView];
```